# Need advice on retrieving data from DB

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a MySQL DB with 2 tables. 
First table:

```
Posts                                    
ID                      
post_title                      
post_content 
... etc
```

And second table with additional data:

```
Postmeta
ID
Post_ID (FK)
meta_key
meta_value
```

The data that I need is in the meta_key/value pairs. But this DB organized in the way that each row in the second table only have one piece of information.

For example (second table):

```
ID      Post_ID   meta_key        meta_value
1          5      info                 30

ID      Post_ID   meta_key        meta_value
2          5      additional_info      40

ID      Post_ID   meta_key        meta_value
3          6      info                 50

ID      Post_ID   meta_key        meta_value
4          6      additional_info      60
```

So if I run query

```
SELECT 
posts.id, 
posts.post_date, 
posts.post_author, 
posts.post_content, 
posts.post_title, 
postmeta.meta_id, 
postmeta.meta_key, 
postmeta.meta_value

FROM posts INNER JOIN postmeta ON posts.id = postmeta.post_id

WHERE posts.post_type = 'post'
```

I get back all data that I need but data from first table (ID/post_content etc) repeated many times.
But I only need data from first table once but all additional data from second table related to ID from the first table.

How I should filter all this stuff? May be some php loop?

Comment: You should use the query you posted to get all the data as it, then in your php application you should output in the format you want, in which each data from first table are the headers of their corresponding items from the second table. You shouldn't format data in SQL, it isn't for formatting data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [mysql group_concat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function like this:

```
select
    posts.id, 
    posts.post_date, 
    posts.post_author, 
    posts.post_content, 
    posts.post_title, 
    group_concat(postmeta.meta_id) as metaID, 
    group_concat(postmeta.meta_key) as metaKey, 
    group_concat(postmeta.meta_value_ as metaValue
from
    posts 
        INNER JOIN postmeta 
            ON posts.id = postmeta.post_id
where
    posts.post_type = 'post'
group by
    posts.id, 
    posts.post_date, 
    posts.post_author, 
    posts.post_content, 
    posts.post_title
```

The to split out the results in PHP you can easily use an explode function to form an array of the resulting information.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM Posts, Postmeta 
WHERE Posts.Post_id = Postmeta.Post_id 
GROUP BY Posts.Post_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `SELECT DISTINCT` instead of just `SELECT`